# WPML equivalent for angular

Tags: wordpress, string, angular, typescript, wpml

I have a wordpress website and i installed WPML plugin. it gives me every strings in all pages and it will be able to translate it later. is there any equivalent method to use in angular2 and get all strings in codes both front-end and back-end?

Comment: Angular is only used in the Frontend. You need a different technology for the backend. So, since Angular cannot know the backend, it cannot extract any strings from it.

Comment: @sapanoia is there any way to extract only front-end strings?

Comment: No. I suggest reading up on how internationalization is intended to be done by the platform developers: https://angular.io/guide/i18n